# In elastic search if i set fielddata true to date filed then it only get result. any option for this?

Tags: elasticsearch

I read some related topic it work if i set as :

```
protected $mapping = [
    'properties' => [
        "updated_at" => [
            'type'      => 'text',
            'fielddata' => true,
        ],
    ],
];
```

but it affected on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I misunderstood but you want to reform som kind of analysis/aggregation on the field *updated_at* that should hold a timestamp?
Then I would suggest to change your mapping from `text` to `date`.

*Vide* https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: Ya i set date as well as format to that  field but its not working.